# How to make a custom loader in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to make a custom loader that showcases the logo of my company and runs a line across the border of that logo, that or show different images icons during loading, the icons which I want are relevant to my company's business model which I can make, but I want to know how do I go about making a custom loader in react-native or react...

Comment: You build a component, render them by visibility and in any screens that you prefer to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this https://medium.com/@kelleyannerose/react-native-activityindicator-for-a-quick-easy-loading-animation-593c06c044dc will help.
Once you know how to play around with the animation, you can add more complex animations, the way you want it. Or probably play with svg and images later with animation.

Comment: thanks. but how we can have custom loaders with css animations?